# How to avoid excluding dependencies from the custom jar files

Tags: java, maven, jar, jackson, jackson-databind

I have one application where iam using jackson-core & jackson-databind dependencies.

This application is also using two custom jar files (oms.jar & cms.jar)

These two jar files are two java maven projects which are packaged as a jar files.These two jar files als internally using the jackson-core & jackson-databind dependencies to call webservices etc:

If i run my main application with these two jars included iam getting the exception "com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/exc/InvalidDefinitionException"

When i see the dependancy hierarchy in the pom.xml it shows that jackson-core & jackson-databind  dependencies are ignored because they are available multiple times(in jars & in my application)

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.order.service</groupId>
            <artifactId>oms</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.6</version>
    
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            
        </dependency>
```

full pom.xml

4.0.0
pms
testing
2.0.0-dev-SNAPSHOT
war
http://maven.apache.org

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <spring-version>5.2.22.RELEASE</spring-version>
</properties>


<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-library</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-1.2-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.17.1</version>
        <!-- <scope>test</scope> -->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- JSON Parsing Library -->
    
    

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.17.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.17.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.17.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.6</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
        <artifactId>solr-solrj</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20131018</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jettison</groupId>
        <artifactId>jettison</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>axis</groupId>
        <artifactId>axis</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
        <artifactId>axis2-codegen</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
        <artifactId>axis2-json</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Added file upload dependency to omit fileupload 1.2 from the dependency axis2-kernel -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
        <artifactId>axis2-kernel</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>wsdl4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>wsdl4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>wss4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>wss4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
        <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.neethi</groupId>
        <artifactId>neethi</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.ws.commons.schema</groupId>
        <artifactId>XmlSchema</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.ws.commons.axiom</groupId>
        <artifactId>axiom-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    
    
    
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oms</groupId>
        <artifactId>oms</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.6</version>
    </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.pms</groupId>
        <artifactId>pms</artifactId>
        <version>1.6</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-module-jsonSchema</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.1</version>
    </dependency>

    
</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>testing</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <warSourceDirectory>${basedir}/WebRoot</warSourceDirectory>
                <outputDirectory>
                    ${project.build.directory}/../package/dependencies/jbossews/webapps
                </outputDirectory>
                <warName>testing</warName>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                <descriptors>
                    <descriptor>src/main/assembly/assembly.xml</descriptor>
                </descriptors>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
            <configuration>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

If i exclude the dependencies then the application is working.

Can't we avoid this exclusion and run amy application.how to approach in this scenario.please give ur suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You ran into the common situation that your dependencies (`oms.jar` and `cms.jar`) are using different version of `jackson` than your application.

If you have different versions in the dependencies, Maven chooses one of them, but it does not always choose wisely.

Best thing is to figure out which version might work for both you and your dependencies (often the newer one, or some version in between the two versions) and fix that version in `<dependencyManagement>` or in your own `<dependency>`.

Answer (score -1):

Try including the dependencies as `<scope>runtime</scope>` dependencies in your pom. This will override the versions that are transiently being included.

Comment: Hi @Jonathan S. Fisher ,Thanks for your answer.This <scope>runtime</scope> should be included in the custom jar files or in my main application?.If i put scope runtime in my main application then application is not getting compiled,getting compile errors in java classes where iam using jackson library.can you please suggest for this.

Comment: post your full pom.xml and the output and I can take a look

Comment: Hi @Jonathan S. Fisher ,I have posted my pom.xml in my question.can u please take a look.if you look at the end the oms jar & pms jar also have jackson-dependancies and the main application also have jackson-dependancies.Can you suggest here in this scenario please.iam getting exception "com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/exc/InvalidDefinitionException"